# Java primitive data types size

Tags: java

Hi I am learning Java basics. I need to check the size of primitive data types like using `sizeof();` in c language.

Example code:

```
int i;
System.out.print(sizeof(i));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Comment: If you type the title of your question into Google the first result gives you the answer

Comment: For which purpose you need this?

Comment: Not for any specific purpose! Just need to know if any possibilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need for such a thing in Java since the sizes of the primitives are set for all JVMs (unlike C where they can vary).

`char` is 16 bit (actually an unsigned quantity), `int` is 32 bit, `long` is 64 bit.

`boolean` is the ugly sister in all this. Internally it is manipulated as a 32 bit `int`, but arrays of `boolean`s use 1 byte per element.

Comment: I see no reason to call boolean the ugly sister. Internally bytes, shorts and chars are also often manipulated as 32-bit integers. User just should not care about these internals.

Comment: @TagirValeev The fact is that there is no language definition for the size of `boolean`. All the rest of the types have that size defined in their wrapper classes (SIZE constant representing number of bits). You can write all types into a ByteBuffer - except boolean, etc.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, your comment sounds reasonable, but the "Internally it is manipulated as a 32 bit `int`" statement in the answer is not.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `BYTES` constants (since Java 8) in the corresponding boxed classes:

```
sizeof(int) -> Integer.BYTES
sizeof(long) -> Long.BYTES
sizeof(char) -> Character.BYTES
sizeof(short) -> Short.BYTES
sizeof(float) -> Float.BYTES
sizeof(double) -> Double.BYTES
sizeof(byte) -> Byte.BYTES
```

Note that reference and boolean sizes are not defined, it's implementation-specific. In general you rarely should care about their size.

Comment: Pre java-8 you could use the `SIZE` constant, just need to know that they give the representation in bits instead of bytes.